# tab menu corresponding button active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Hello I am making a tab menu right now.
My problem is that I want to give is-active when the button is clicked, but I don't know what value to put in the empty space there.

```
type Props = {
  title: string
  index: number
  setSelectedTab: (index: number) => void
}

const TabTitle: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ title, setSelectedTab, index }) => {
  
  // The value to be activated. Initial value is `0th button`
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  

  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    setSelectedTab(index)
  }, [setSelectedTab, index])


  return (
    <li>
      <button
      key={index}
      className={activeIndex === [empty place] ? "is-active" : ""} 
      onClick={() => onClick()}
      >
        {title}
        </button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

```
 console.log(index);
  // 0
  // 1 
  // 2
```

How to use the index value `If you click the 0th button, index : 0`
`If ​​you click the 1st button, index: 1`
After making it like this, `className={activeIndex === index ? "is-active" : ""}` If you put `index` , it will work normally, but I don't know how to make an index like that.

How can I set the index to give  first click 0 second click 1 ​according to the clicked value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the `index` property to the `selectedTab` property (which presumably exists on the parent component, since you pass `setSelectedTab` function to the `TabTitle` component).

```
import { useCallback } from "react";

type Props = {
  title: string;
  index: number;
  selectedTab: number; // <-- this should be passed by the parent 
  setSelectedTab: (index: number) => void;
};

const TabTitle: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  title,
  selectedTab,
  setSelectedTab,
  index
}) => {
  const onClick = useCallback(
    (index) => {
      setSelectedTab(index);
    },
    [setSelectedTab]
  );

  return (
    <li>
      <button
        key={index}
        className={selectedTab === index ? "is-active" : ""} // it's active if its index is the same as the selected tab
        onClick={() => onClick(index)} // <-- so it knows which button was clicked
      >
        {title}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
};

export default TabTitle;
```

You can see a [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dubinsky-5xhv4?file=/src/TabTitle.tsx) on codesandbox.

Comment: Hello, this is an extra question, but I have one thing to ask.
If I want to put different black and white images in the title part.
And when the title becomes active, I'm trying to make it into a colored image, can you give me a hint.... I'm sorry

Comment: Yes, it's easy if your images are in full color to begin with. Then you can apply the CSS `grayscale` filter when they are not active. I've updated the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dubinsky-5xhv4?file=/src/TabTitle.tsx) to show how it can work.

Comment: You are truly a genius. I would be happy if someone like you was a mentor for the company. Thank you.